# "Откорректировать" или "скорректировать" план? Перспективы "к установлению" или "установления"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать: "Откорректировать план" или "Скорректировать план"?
"Перспективы к установлению" или "перспективы установления"?

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях зависит от контекста. 
Я сейчас, возможно, крамольную вещь скажу, но я в теорию единственной видовой пары не верю. Любой глагол, образованный приставочным методом от глагола несовершенного вила помимо завершенности действия (т.е. образования т.н. видовой пары) несет и дополнительный признак образа, обстоятельства и т.п. действия.
В данном случае оба варианта "скорректировать" и "откорректировать" несут признак не просто завершения действия, но его **результативной** законченности. Поэтому семантической разницы между вариантами я не вижу. А вот стилистическая есть. Скорректировать - более нейтрально. "Откорректировать" подразумевает некоторые сопутствующие обстоятельста.

Вот с перспективами - тут действительно смысловые различия. В обычном контексте, конечно, **перспективы установления**. "К установлению" - это скорее не перспекиты установления, а перспективы какой-то предварительной работе.
Ну и в профессиональном жаргоне архитекторов, например, значения тоже могут различаться, но это видимо, не наш случай.

Answer (score 0):

Скорректировать - видовая пара к глаголу корректировать (Что делать? - корректировать; Что сделать  - скорректировать). Приставка ОТ- придает значение завершенности действия. Откорректировать - скорректировать окончательно.
Слово "перспектива" требует родительного падежа: перспективы чего?